# Quotient group $G/\{1\}=G$ if $1$ is the identity element of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that quotient group $G/\{1\}=G$? Or isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: Yes, if $E=\{e\}$ is the trivial subgroup, then the quotient homomorphism $G \rightarrow G/E$ given by $g \mapsto gE=\{g\}$ is clearly bijective.

Comment: It's isomorphic to $G$. The elements of $G/\{1\}$ are the singleton sets $\{g\}$ for each $g \in G$. There's not much value in making this distinction in most cases, so there's not much harm to consider $G/\{1\} = G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The map $id:G\to G:g\mapsto g$ is surjective, and its kernel is $\{e\}$, so by the first isomorphism theorem, $G/ker\ id = G/\{e\} \cong G$.