# What $\mathbb Z/\ker f$ mean if $f$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Here, I am trying to really understand the concept of cosets. From my understanding, given groups A and B, then A/B would mean the set of all the cosets of B in A. In that case, if I have  $\mathbb Z/\ker f$, and $f$ is injective, does that  mean I have infinitely many cosets with only one element, or the entire $\mathbb Z$? Please help me understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: What are $A,B$? Groups, rings, modules, vector spaces? Usually $f$ injective means $\ker(f)=0$. So you need to understand $Z/0$. This has been discussed here several times.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I just edited the question. A and B are groups. I think the question is also the same if A and B are vectors or rings or R-modules. Please enlighten me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Also, I would appreciate it if you could show me any link that discusses Z/0

Comment: Why do we automatically downvote posts that are short and confused (thereby making an answer less likely), when our job is to alleviate confusion for well-intentioned askers? Well, I know why, but we really shouldn't do it. It wouldn't have taken so very long for those downvoters to just simply comment an answer, it being so short, and there is no cause to withhold information here; there is no evidence of homework-problem behaviour or laziness or rudeness or ...

Comment: Mr Prof, for groups, the trivial group is denoted by $1$, and about the quotient group $G/1$ see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925176/quotient-group-g-1-g-if-1-is-the-identity-element-of-g). Have you tried to search yourself for it?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is injective $\Rightarrow$ $Ker(f)=0$, and $a+\{0\}=a$ since $a+B:=\{a+b\,|\, b\in B\}$.

Comment: So, we are basically adding every element of $Z$ to $0$. This means $Z/Kerf$ is $Z$ essentially. Is this correct?

Comment: @MrProf Yes. They are technically different sets so technically different (groups rings modules) but are isomorphic. Many people would just abuse $\Bbb Z/\ker f=\Bbb Z$

Comment: @FShrike Please help me understand why they are "technically" different sets. I just want to understand this at an intuitive level so I can have confidence in it.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer then its coset class in $\Bbb Z/\{0\}$ is $\{n\}$. So the elements of $\Bbb Z/\{0\}$ are of the form $\{n\}$ rather than $n$; in most and probably all constructions of the integers, the sets of form $\{n\}$ are different than the sets of form $n$. But this level of detail, down to the particular models used, is usually irrelevant and intuitively they are absolutely the same thing. We don’t care how we construct our integers just so long as they do what we want. $\Bbb Z/0$ is the group where you set $0=0$… oh wait, that’s not changing anything! So it’s ‘the same’ group.

Comment: @FShrike thanks for the explanation.